# Magento 2, how to deploy the content for specific area only (frontend or adminhtml) as requested parameter but in two languages

Tags: magento2, deploy

To save time when each time I need to deploy the content for changes in one area, how can I provide for example "adminhtml" as argument to be deployed in two languages? Below did not work:

```
bin/magento  setup:static-content:deploy adminhtml en_US nl_NL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  below command for only admin language deploy,

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --area=adminhtml --language en_US --language nl_NL
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2.1.1 you can now deploy specific themes or exclude themes:

Deploy specific themes:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --theme Magento/backend --theme Vendor/mytheme
```

Exclude themes:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy --exclude-theme Magento/luma
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will deploy the content from only specific area with language files

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -l en_US -l nl_NL --area adminhtml
```

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/95972 is this edit correct bro